# Call a function with a separate context with a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script in which a function is called for every element on page. It works well with separate function calls but if I try to call the function with a unique selector it doesn't work properly.
How can I implement a loop to call the function separately for every html block but using only a class (for example if I have X element) and without addressing them with a separate selector like now (startLoop('#stack1'); startLoop('#stack2'); ecc. ecc.)

```
let timer;

function startLoop(container) {
let lastCard = $(container + ' .card').length - 1;
  timer = setInterval(function () {
    let prependList = function() {
      if( $(container + ' .card').hasClass('activeNow') ) { 
        let $slicedCard = $(container + ' .card').slice(lastCard).removeClass('transformThis activeNow');
        $(container + ' ul.card-list').prepend($slicedCard);
      }
    }
    
    $(container + ' li.card').last().addClass('transformThis').prev().addClass('activeNow');
    setTimeout(function(){prependList(); }, 250);
  }, 4500);
}

 if ($('#stack1')[0]) {
  startLoop('#stack1');
}

if ($('#stack2')[0]) {
  startLoop('#stack2');
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing the point, but this seems like it might be an unnecessarily complicated solution, what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Start here: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/  Create it as a plugin, then use `$(".stack").startLoop()`

Comment: or `$(".stack").each(function() { startLoop(this); }` (which is essentially what you would do if you created a full plugin)

Comment: @DBS i'm trying to make the call to the function independent from the number of element I have in page. They can be 10, 100 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try it with [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) ?

Suppose you want to loop through all the elements that have class `.stacks`

So if you want to loop through all the elements of class `.stacks`, then you may write it like below:

```
$(function(){
    $(".stacks").each(function(index, element){
        var elementId = $(element).attr("id");
        startLoop("#" + elementId);
    });
});

// from here your codes start
let timer;

function startLoop(container) {

    let lastCard = $(container).find('.card').length - 1;
      timer = setInterval(function () {
        let prependList = function() {
          if( $(container + ' .card').hasClass('activeNow') ) { 
            let $slicedCard = $(container + ' .card').slice(lastCard).removeClass('transformThis activeNow');
            $(container + ' ul.card-list').prepend($slicedCard);
          }
        }
        
        $(container + ' li.card').last().addClass('transformThis').prev().addClass('activeNow');
        setTimeout(function(){prependList(); }, 250);
      }, 4500);

}
```

Comment: Or, just use `element.id` in place of `$(element).attr('id')`. In fact, you could change `startLoop` to add `const $container = $(container)` and use `$container.find(selector)` instead of `$(container + selector)` and then use `$("stacks").each((_, el) => startLoop(el));`, but I digress :).

Comment: In your `each` you can just do `startLoop(element)` as the first line is `$(container)` - so you don't need to convert so an `#id` selector (in fact that would be a bad idea as it would mean otherwise unused ids would be needed on everything)